# Saving user input to local storage

Tags: javascript, save, local-storage

I have the code to save user input for a single input box here and i would like to have it save multiple user inputs. I have asked people and they have told me to do things i dont fully understand, could someone rewrite this for me to where i can have multiple ids? Id rather not right this 20+ times for each individual id. Thanks!

```
var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("name")

    function save(){
        var Item = document.getElementById("name").value;
        localStorage.setItem("name", Item);
    }
    function get(){
        document.getElementById('name').value = localStorage.getItem('name');

        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the id of the field to the function and save/get it that way

```js
function save(id) {
    var Item = document.getElementById(id).value;
    localStorage.setItem(id, Item);
}

function get(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = localStorage.getItem(id);
}
```